# Xamarin disable blinking/flickering listview when tapped

Tags: listview, xamarin

How to disable blinking/flickering listview in Xamarin when tapped? I write shared code (Android is ok, but in iOS blinking is present). It is observable collection. One row of listview consist of: labels, buttons and images. Only pressing buttons makes action.

- `ViewCell IsEnabled=false` - no more blinking but it also disable buttons
- `Listview SelectionMode=None` - not working
- `Listview SelectedItem="{Binding X}"`  where X in code-behind is null - not working
- `Listview ItemTapped="{Binding Y}"` where Y in code-behind is null - not working
- in XAML put one level up to listview:

`<Frame>` 
`<Frame.GestureRecognizers>`
`TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCardCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"` - where TapCardCommand executes nothing - not working

Have you got any other idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the **CustomRenderer** of **ViewCell** in your iOS project and set the style of selectionStyle.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(MyViewCellRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
  public class MyViewCellRenderer:ViewCellRenderer
  {
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
    {

        var cell=base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);

        cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

        return cell;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This solution works! Thank you Lucas Zhang. 
I just had to add empty public class MyViewCell : ViewCell in PCL project and add your class in iOS project. Works great.